# Show how long the tar command takes to complete archiving process

Tags: linux, time, tar

Is there any way show how long did the compression time took to archive files using tar command.

I need to know how many times took archiving process.

I searched the internet but couldn't find anything related to this question.

Answer (score 3):

The `tar` itself does not provide a built-in option to display the time it took to compress or archive files,but you can use the `time` in combination with `tar` to measure the execution time.

```
time tar -czvf archive.tar.gz /path/to/your_files
```

you can also use the `time` in combination with `date` because it allows you to calculate the exact time difference before and after the execution of the `tar`, in my scenario, the `date +%s` is used to get the current time in seconds before and after running the `tar` and the difference between the two timestamps is then calculated and stored in the `runtime` variable and finally, the script displays the total time taken in seconds, something like this:

```
start=$(date +%s)
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz /path/to/your_files
end=$(date +%s)
runtime=$((end-start))
echo "Time taken: $runtime seconds"
```